# Oracle SQL - Displaying only net effect (unmatched) rows

Tags: sql, oracle

Following is my sample table structure

```
Name    Amount
A          100
A          100
A         -100
A          100
A          100
A         -100
B           10
A          100
```

There is no Primary Key in this table.

Desired Output:

```
Name    Amount
A          100
A          100
B           10
A          100
```

Explanation:
I need to cancel out matching rows, i.e., one -100 nullifies one +100. 
Therefore i need to display only rows that are not offset / not nullified one to one.

This can be done in PL/SQL by populating the rows to a temporary table and deleting *one* positive for every *one* corresponding negative. However, I require to do this on the fly using SQL statements.

Regards,
Raghu

Comment: *"There is no Primary Key in this table"* tsk, tsk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enumerate the rows using `row_number()` and then use that to "cancel" them:

```
select t.name, t.amount
from (select t.*,
             sum(amount) over (partition by name, abs(amount), seqnum) as sum_amount
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by name, amount order by name) as seqnum
            from t
           ) t
      ) t
where sum_amount <> 0;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ee5e130b6e936c4132b691969d3903e6) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You can give each row a `ROW_NUMBER` unique to that `name`/`amount` pair and then count whether, for a `name`/`ABS(amount)` there are one or two values for each of those `ROW_NUMBER` and discard the rows where there are two (one positive and one negative):

```sql
SELECT name,
       amount
FROM   (
  SELECT name,
         amount,
         COUNT( amount ) OVER ( PARTITION BY name, ABS( amount ), rn )
           AS num_matches
  FROM   (
    SELECT t.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY name, amount ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS rn
    FROM   table_name t
  )
)
WHERE num_matches = 1
```

So, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( Name, Amount ) AS
SELECT 'A', +100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', +100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', -100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', +100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', +100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', -100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B',  +10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', +100 FROM DUAL;
```

This outputs:

> ```
> NAME | AMOUNT
> :--- | -----:
> A    |    100
> A    |    100
> A    |    100
> B    |     10
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=75db5a976bc0471f7f6c0da64928405d)*

Answer (score 0):

If there are never more negative values than positive it's a task for EXCEPT ALL. Oracle doesn't support it, but this is a rewrite:

```
select name, amount
from
 (
   select name, amount, row_number() over (partition by name, amount order by amount)
   from tab
   where amount > 0
   minus
   select name, -amount, row_number() over (partition by name, amount order by amount)
   from tab
   where amount < 0
 ) dt
```

or

```
with cte as 
 (
   select name, amount, row_number() over (partition by name, amount order by amount) as rn
   from tab
 )
select name, amount
from
 (
   select name, amount, rn
   from cte
   where amount > 0
   minus
   select name, -amount, rn
   from cte
   where amount < 0
 ) dt
```